# Does the Treaty of Algeron forbid civilian ownership of cloaking devices?

Tags: star-trek

The Treaty of Algeron forbids the Federation development or use of cloaking devices. This explains the lack of cloaking device equipped ships in Starfleet, the military arm of the Federation. However, does the Treaty of Algeron forbid Federation member races from developing, building or using cloaking devices in the civilian market?
Could Wesley Crusher, in theory, quit Starfleet and start a private company called *Crushers Cloaks* that designs, builds and sells cloaking devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We actually have extremely little consistent, canonical information about **anything** regarding civilian life or law enforcement in the Federation; and what we have is wildly inconsistent. It's therefore just about impossible to answer this question from the standpoint of canonical information. There simply is no truly comparable event in any of the series.

There are various "sensitive" technologies that are clearly considered bad ideas for people to play with, but there's little evidence that they're tightly regulated Federation-wide. David Marcus was able to use protomatter, for example, despite its instability, in a Federation-funded project. Genetic engineering is tightly controlled, and yet when Bashir was discovered to be genetically enhanced, the Federation did not appear to try to go after the doctors who did it, but after his parents for having had it done.

If we were to go on that precedent, the Federation would not prevent civilians from experimenting with or even constructing cloaking devices; but they may well attempt to punish anyone actually **using** one, civilian or otherwise, within Federation space. Assuming, of course, they could catch them :-D

Answer (score 0):

I believe the treaty binds all 150 or so member worlds of the Federation. If one member race tries to violate it, the most likely scenario would be a vote taken by the [Federation Council](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Federation#The_Legislature) to take action against them. Whether it will be diplomacy, sanctions or military action will, of course, depend on the vote.

As for individuals attempting this, I believe local regulations will come into effect.

Usually the Federation does not impede individuals acting against the interests of the Federation unless there is a security threat (which cloaking technology is). For instance, they allowed the [Hansens](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Hansen_family) to leave the Alpha Quadrant in search of the Borg, without even filing a flight plan.